# Visual studio 2008 - which version in future job

Tags: visual-studio-2008

From beginning I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional from MSDNAA[ I am C# and ASP.NET programmer Student], but I see at MSDNAA Team System and Team Suite version of Visual Studio 2008 . I am also looking forward for 1st jobs and I have question...

In developing, programming etc in Real jobs You use standard version Professional or one of Teams ? I am find that they have similar features, but I hear that Team version in more Pro/ Enterprise.

I have possibilities to download Team version from MSDNAA, but You think that I should ?

Comment: Yes team system is much more Pro/ Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with Kornel's post. However would also add that when I'm looking at a candidate for a development position, I'd probably not be too interested in the candiates experience with TFS (or for that matter any source control system or other system/tool that might be used, IE Cruise Control, Hudson, TRAC etc). I very much concentrate on their approach to development, how they think about problems and their core skills as a developer. If they know about TFS, SVN, CVS or anything else that's great, but it wouldn't get me to hire them if I had doubts about their core skills.

I guess I'm saying I'd concentrate on becoming as good a developer as you possibly can. You'll get introduced to the other things as you gain experience in your place of work. Pretty much any .NET codeing house is going to make use of a good developer utilising the .NET framework well. Not everyone uses TFS and the like.

Comment: Yes, i know that core skill is the most important, but as I am student with MSDNAA free stuff possibilities and last semester at university before me I think about learn as much I can before i will send my cv. So like Kornel write.."All knowledge that you gain for free  is knowledge that will not hurt you" but can help You ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask if you should. All knowledge that you gain for free (while you still have access to MSDNAA) is knowledge that will not hurt you ;).